# How to create an add view like Stocks app ios

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I'm wondering how to implement a view with a searchbar on top, already "opened" as the stocks app in ios. I tried with a navigation bar, but also if it hides when i tap on the searchbar field, is not the same thing as Apple's. Any suggestions?

The view I'm talking about is reached when, opening the stocks app, you tap on the bottom right icon, then the "plus" icon on the top left.

[image: The search view]

Comment: You might want to show what you have tried and others may be able to help you make the change to what you want.

Comment: Do you mean `UISearchBar` or `UISearchDisplayController`?

Comment: isn't that just a search bar?

Comment: @rocky i was just thinking the same thing... its just different color schemes and uses a different search button.

Comment: Yes, that is a search bar. http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-add-search-bar-uitableview/

Comment: Thanks everyone. The question was "how can i show ONLY the searchBar, without the navigation bar. I found tue solution with: self.searchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES

Answer (score 0):

Just pick up a UISearchBar from the Object library on the bottom right of Xcode and place it over your UITableView in the storyboard or in the xib. You should see a blue line with two dots at the left and right hand sides over the tableView, that's the place where the UISearchBar must be placed.

Now your UIViewController (or UITableViewController) subclass should implement the UISearchBarDelegate protocol and override its methods. Don't forget to set your viewController as delegate of the UISearchBar you placed before.